# A subsequence of a Markov chain is a Markov chain

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains

How to show it?
In other words, I want to show that if $  \{X_n\}$ is a Markov chain then for every $ n\in\mathbb{N} $ and $ 1\le i_1<\dots<i_k\le n $ such that $P(X_{i_1}=x_1,\dots ,X_{i_k}=x_k)>0 $ it holds that $ P(X_{n+1}=x |X_{i_1}=x_1,\dots ,X_{i_k}=x_k)=P(X_{n+1}=x |X_{i_k}=x_k) $

I have tried to prove it by induction on $n$ and by using the formula
$ P(X_{n+1}=x|A)= \sum_{a} P(X_n=a|A)P(X_{n+1}=x|A,X_n=a)$ where $A=\{X_{i_1}=x_1,\dots ,X_{i_k}=x_k\}$, but the expression $P(X_{n+1}=x|A,X_n=a)$ isn't any better.
Another attempt was to "fill the holes": let $\{j_1,\dots,j_{m}\}=\{1,\dots,n\}\setminus\{i_1,\dots i_k\}$ so
$\\ P(X_{n+1}=x|A)=\sum_{b_1,\dots , b_m}P(X_{n+1}=x|A,X_{j_1}=b_1, \dots ,X_{j_m}=b_m)P(X_{j_1}=b_1, \dots ,X_{j_m}=b_m|A) $ but again I didn't know how to deal with the second expression.

Comment: What have you tried? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: I added it to the question @Saad

Answer (score 1):

Interesting problem. Here are some thoughts.

The usual Markov criterion is that each item depends only on the one before it. That is, its probability distribution is the same regardless of the prior elements:

[image: A series of dots, the last two X_n and X_n+1, with a dotted line walling off the prior dots]

Your problem is slightly different. You have deleted some elements from the sequence, and you want to prove that the next element depends only on the last element not deleted:

[image: Similar, but some dots have been grayed out]

One case to consider is where $i_k = n$:

[image: Similar, but last not-grayed-out dot is second-to-last dot]

See if you can prove it for that case first. Once you have proven it for $i_k = n$, consider a case where $n$ is a little ahead of $i_k$, that is, where $i_k + m = n$ for some $m$:

[image: Similar, but now the last not-grayed-out dot is some steps away from the last dot]

Comment: I still can't see how to use the assumption $i_k = n$

Comment: @MCL Try the simplest case of $k = 2$, $i_k = n = 3$, and "fill the holes" as you suggest in your question.

Comment: @Owen is there a name for this theorem and where could I find the proof? Thank you for your time!

Comment: @Anonymous I don't know the name. If you post another question I can post the whole proof. But the basic idea is to "fill the holes" as MCL says. Consider $P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_n=x_n) = P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_1=x_1, ..., X_n=x_n)$ (the usual Markov condition) and try to show $P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_n=x_n) = P(X_{n+1}=x_{n+1}|X_1=x_1, ..., X_{h-1}=x_{h-1}, X_{h+1}=x_{h+1}, ...,  X_n=x_n)$ (one hole at $h$). This involves summing over the space of $X_h$. It's a special case of the general rule that if $A$ is independent of $(B, C)$ jointly, $A$ is independent of $B$.