# Markov Chains Concatenation Prohibited?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, solution-verification, markov-chains, information-theory

Assuming $X_1,...,X_4$ are discrete random variables, consider the following 2 Markov Chains:

- $C_1:X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow X_3$
- $C_2:X_2 \rightarrow X_3 \rightarrow X_4$

I was trying to prove that $C_3: X_1 \rightarrow X_2 \rightarrow X_3 \rightarrow X_4$ is also a Markov Chain.
(It is known that the inverse of this statement is true, if interested, see the relative post [A subsequence of a Markov chain is a Markov chain](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3649992/a-subsequence-of-a-markov-chain-is-a-markov-chain/))

After failing to prove this, I tried constructing a **counterexample**. *I think I made it, but I would like some verification at least.*

I will make the following assumptions

- $X_1 \perp X_2$ ($\perp$ denotes independence)
- $X_2 = X_3$
- $X_4 = X_3 + X_1$

**With this setup**, **$C_1$ is a Markov chain** since $X_3$ is a function of $X_2$.
Hence, $p(x_3|x_2,x_1) = p(x_3|x_2)$.

Also since $X_2$ is a function of $X_3$, it holds:
$$X_4 \rightarrow X_3 \rightarrow X_2 \iff X_2 \rightarrow X_3 \rightarrow X_4$$
Thus **$C_2$ is also a Markov chain**.

In order for $C_3$ to be a Markov chain, it suffices to show that $p(x_4|x_3,x_2,x_1) = p(x_4|x_3)$

- $p_1 = p(X_4 = x_4|X_3 = x_3) = p(X_1 + x_3 = x_4| X_3 = x_3) = p(X_1 = x_4 - x_3)$
- $p_2 = p(x_4|x_3,x_2,x_1) = p(\{x_1 + x_3 = x_4\}) \cdot \delta[x_3-x_2] = \delta[x_4-x_3-x_1] \cdot \delta[x_3-x_2]$

where $\delta[x] = \left\{
\begin{array}{ll}
       1     ,& x = 0\\
      0 ,& x \ne0\\
\end{array} 
\right.$

Since in general $p_1 \neq p_2$(e.g. if $X_1 \sim \{1/2,1/2\}$), **$C_3$ is not a Markov chain in general**. Therefore, concatenation is probably prohibited, at least without further assumptions. $\square$

Thanks in advance, for the help!

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: Good to hear, thanks!